# git remote -v differ from config

Tags: git, version-control, repo

i stumble upon strange git problem when trying to sync

fatal: Project not found: platform_testing

My repo config looks like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://my_gerrit_instance.com/platform/platform_testing
    projectname = platform/platform_testing
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

But git remote -v returns

```
origin  ssh://my_gerrit_instance.com/platform_testing (fetch)
origin  ssh://my_gerrit_instance.com/platform_testing (push)
```

That git is part of android mirror, path in my manifest is correct one.

```
<project groups="pdk-fs,pdk-cw-fs,cts" name="platform/platform_testing" path="platform_testing"/>
```

I deleted the project and repo sync again, not working.

Tried to add a second remote, also appears with wrong path.

tried to edit the remote with git remote set-url not helping.

That happened all of a sudden...Couple of days ago was working perfectly fine.

Comment: Does `git remote set-url origin ssh://my_gerrit_instance.com/platform/platform_testing` not work either? Has anyone modified the code of `repo` which you can check by `git log` and `git status` in `.repo/repo` under the root of your aosp codebase? Is `url.<base>.insteadOf` specified in your `git config -l`?

Comment: git remote set-url is not working. But you are right someone defined isnteadOf on this server.

Comment: What does `pdk-cw-fs` mean in the `groups` definition?

Comment: It's just name of a group that Google uses for some Android platform gits

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/5ce2fd2c5489b9cca4022aaa7543474d7f625439/default.xml